# Greenpacket UH235 / MediaTek MT7118 WiMAX Modem

Tags: 12.04, modem

I have a greenpacket USB wimax modem that works in Windows but not in Ubuntu 12.04.Searched google but am yet to see a solution. The modem uses MediaTek chipset. Has anybody been able to find a solution for this please?

Answer (score 1):

No good news: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-nettool/+question/139831
It looks there are only drivers for 32bit linux and kernel version 2.6.28 (old! ubuntu jaunty 9.04). No new drivers on the horizon yet.